# Como llamar un metodo que es general con Activeform?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo una aplicacion con muchos formularios que tienen todos unos metodos especificos como Crear,Modificar,Guardar y en el formulario principal tengo una barra de herramientas que deberia Acceder a estos metodos  dependiendo de el formulario activo, en este momento lo tengo asi pero en la aplicacion se espera tener demasiados formularios y hacerlos todos asi o con un switch me llevaria mucho codigo:

```
foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms) {

            if (form.Name == ActiveForm.Name) {

              Xformulario  objformulario=(Xformulario) form;
              objformulario.guardar();
                break;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar interfaces.

```
public interface IFormulario
{
    // cambia la definición de los métodos a como los uses en tu programa
    void Crear();  
    void Modificar();
    void Guardar();

    string Name { get; }
}
```

Luego, has que tus formularios implementen la interfaz:

```
public class Xformulario : Form, IFormulario
{
    public void Crear()
    {
        // implementación del método crear
    }

    public void Modificar()
    {
        // implementación del método Modificar
    }

    public void Guardar()
    {
        // implementación del método Guardar
    }

    // la propiedad Name ya existe en la clase Form, no es necesario implementarla

    // resto de la clase
}
```

Y por último, utiliza Linq para evitar los ifs/switch:

```
var formulario = Application.OpenForms
    // te va a devolvar solo los formularios que implementan la interfaz IFormulario
    .OfType<IFormulario>() 
    // y con esto nos traemos el formulario que concuerde con el nombre
    .FirstOrDefault(form => form.Name == ActiveForm.Name);

if (formulario != null)
{
    // ya que formulario es de tipo IFormulario, puedes mandar llamar a Guardar sin problemas
    formulario.Guardar();
}
```

Comment: Observación: `Cast<T>` intentará convertir todos los elementos en el tipo indicado, si no puede hacerlo lanzará un excepción.  Si deseas filtrar y obtener solo los del tipo deseado, utiliza `OfType<T>`.

Comment: @DiegoTorres tienes razón, había probado con Cast pero sin materializar el enumerable, de ahí que a mi no me saltaba ninguna excepción.